# Access Metadata set from cmd line in RobotFramework

Tags: robotframework

In case of setting Metadata for top-level test suites with the `--metadata` command line option (as described [here](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#setting-free-metadata)) I don't see any working variants of accessing Metadata items (via `&{SUITE METADATA}` automatic variable, as mentioned [here](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/3.0.4/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#automatic-variables)) within the Test Suite.

Namely, when running

```sh
pybot --metadata prettyMetaName:someMetaValue ...
```

trying to get key `prettyMetaName` in the test suite setup with `&{SUITE METADATA}[prettyMetaName]`, I get this error:

```
Parent suite setup failed:
Dictionary variable '&{SUITE METADATA}' has no key 'prettyMetaName'.
```

More detailed part of the test:

```
*** Keywords ***
Custom Setup
    Log     &{SUITE METADATA}[prettyMetaName]     level=WARN

*** Settings ***
Suite Setup     Custom Setup
```

But if I try to get metadata via python library Listener API, I'm getting the valid result.

On the other hand, in case of explicit declaring Metadata in the Settings section, everything works as expected.

I'm using Robot 3.0.4.

Comment: What's the output when you log `${SUITE METADATA}` - either by `Log` or `Log Dictionary` - in what form is your metadata present there?

Comment: @TodorMinakov

An empty dict (in case when I don't declare it in Settings explicitly, just mention in the comman line args):
[ WARN ] {}

Comment: That's quite strange, I couldn't reproduce it - metadata set on the CLI is a part of the `${SUITE METADATA}` when logging it in the suite setup. The same if adding metadata in a case, or in the settings of the suite, and printing it later on. I'm using v3.1 though - yet, I would be surprised if it didn't work in 3.0.4 and was not noticed up until now.

Comment: I guess you are not trying to access the metadata in the very first suite, aka. top suite. It will be available only there. @TodorMinakov any thoughts on that? Command line arg sets the top suite metadata, which is not inherited by any of the children suites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need an `__init__.robot` file in the root folder of your robot project with the following content.

```
*** Settings ***
Suite Setup       Store Top Suite Metadata


*** Keywords ***
Store Top Suite Metadata
    Set Suite Variable   ${TOP SUITE METADATA}    ${SUITE METADATA}    children=True
```

Then you can use the `${TOP SUITE METADATA}` variable everywhere else to get access to the metadata set by command line arguments.